# Write browserify output to variable

Tags: node.js, express, browserify

I'm running an experiment where I want to write the output of browserify to a variable, to be able to serve it from memory later on. I'm writing to file right now:

```
const b = browserify(path.join(__dirname, '../src/main.js'));
b.transform('babelify');

const dest = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, '../bundles/default.js'));

b.bundle().pipe(dest);
```

But what I want is to assign it to an object, sort of like so:

```
const scripts = {
  default: b.bundle()
};
```

How do I go about this? Listen to the `end` event and then assign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bundle()` [accepts a callback](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#bbundlecb):

```
b.bundle(function(err, buf) {
  if (err) throw err;
  scripts.default = buf.toString();
  ...
});
```

(it's async, of course)